# SAS Loop then Append tables

Tags: loops, macros, sas, append

I am creating multiple datasets named "Taxes&i" (&i notes each new dataset according to the counter I. ) 
The issue I am having is after the loop I am appending the tables.

When I use the code provided from this link,  https://support.sas.com/kb/48/810.html I have issues taking my code that I have now and making it flow with this code. I want to use Work instead of abc. as my libname. For my counters I want to use &i  and &n instead of  the 'count' and instead of name I want to insert taxes.

When I use &i instead of 8. I get an error that says invalid reference and when I change name to taxes I get 18 errors that vary.

```
%macro loop(list1, list2);

  %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&list1, %str('')));
  %do i=1 %to &n; 
    %let O_list1 = %scan(&list1, &i, %str('');
    %let O_list2 = %scan(&list2, &i, %str('');

data taxes&i;
   food=3*&O_List1;
   materials = 4*&O_List2;

%end;
%mend; 

run;

%list('1' '2', '3' '4') /*( this is "O_List1", "O_List2") */
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have an append so it's hard to see how you're trying to follow the sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do that.

An easier way is to use the shortcut list, since you state they're all labeled TAXES&I.

This will append all datasets from Taxes1 to Taxes18.

```
data want;
  set abc.taxes1-abc.taxes18;
run;
```

This will append all datasets that start with the word TAXES.

```
data want;
   set abc.taxes: ;
run;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!